# Installing massif-visualizer on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, package-management, valgrind

I'd like to install massif-visualizer on Ubuntu 14.04.

By default, there's no such package on that release. Which repository contains that package?

```
$ sudo apt-get install massif-visualizer
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package massif-visualizer
```

Comment: http://packages.ubuntu.com/utopic/massif-visualizer No Trusty...

Comment: If I look at this: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+package/massif-visualizer " Run your application in Valgrind with --tool=massif and then open the
 generated massif.out.%pid in the visualizer. Gzip or Bzip2 compressed Massif
 files can also be opened transparently." I would assume you need http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/valgrind

Comment: Rinzwind, your link solved the issue. I downloaded the .deb file and it's working.

Comment: Gratz! :) If you want you can post what you did as an answer and gain some rep ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a working massif-visualizer on Ubuntu 14.04, thanks Rinzwind!

Here is what made it work:

1. Go to launchpad page for [massif visualizer](http://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+package/massif-visualizer).
2. Under 'Published versions' section select the correct arch, and then download the .deb package.
3. Install the package (thanks Pandya):

   ```
   sudo gdebi -i massif-visualizer_0.3-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb
   ```

Comment: Suggestion:Using `sudo gdebi` instead of only `sudo dpkg` is helpful for getting any dependencies if required.(future-help)

Answer (score 12):

**`massif-visualizer`** is available on 3rd Party Repository: [Kubuntu-ppa Backports](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/kubuntu-ppa_backports?dist=trusty)

Install by following command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install massif-visualizer
```

Comment: http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/kubuntu-ppa_backports/trusty/main/base/massif-visualizer

Answer (score 4):

On Ubuntu 18.04 I just needed to install it with:

`sudo apt-get install massif-visualizer`

In case it is relevant to anyone.

Answer (score 0):

For me the link to the launchpad page for massif-visualizer yields a page that tells me it is not available for trusty.

So the answer is unhelpful/wrong, at least now.  (It may have been valid when it was written, who knows.)

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the package for 64-bit from this page provided by Pandya:
https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/kubuntu-ppa_backports/trusty/main/base/massif-visualizer

Put the package in the directory then followed the instructions:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install massif-visualizer
```

It works as a charm!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please don't add 'thanks' as answers. Invest some time in the site and you will gain sufficient [privileges](http://askubuntu.com/privileges) to upvote answers you like, which is the Ask Ubuntu way of saying thank you.